# How to fix " 'audiogrep' is not recognized as an internal or external command"?

Tags: python, speech-to-text

I am trying to figure out how to use [audiogrep](https://github.com/antiboredom/audiogrep).  In command line, I installed audiogrep using

```
pip install audiogrep
```

and installed pocketphinx

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip install --upgrade pocketsphinx
```

When I tried executing the command to transcribe, I get following error in command line.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\PycharmProjects\Audiogrep

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\PycharmProjects\Audiogrep>audiogrep --input data/*.mp3 --transcribe
'audiogrep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

In the Audiogrep directory, I have two .mp3 files in the directory data.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this: `python -m audiogrep --input data/*.mp3 --transcribe`

Comment: You may need to run this where the file `audiogrep.py` is, not the folder `audiogrep`. AFAIK the original command is meant to run on Linux OS so its a bit different to run on Window

Comment: The command is meant to run in Linux?  It would have been nice if the author had included that information so that I didn't waste hours of my time trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong trying to run it on Windows.  Do you know how to run it with Python code?  I see in audiogrep.py there is a function called transcribe(files=[], pre=10, post=50) once I did an "import audiogrep", but I don't know what to put as an input.

Comment: As I comment above, you could still use that command in Window but you will need to run it inside the `audiogrep` folder (which has the file `audiogrep.py`) and you will need to move `data` (with the `.mp3` stuff) folder into `audiogrep` folder too.

Comment: And to import the function in `audiogrep.py` you can use `from audiogrep import audiogrep`  and then `audiogrep.transcribe(...)`, please note that in the import command the first `audiogrep` means the folder and the second one means the `audiogrep.py` file